# tableView.registerClass in swift is fatal error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I use Xcode7

i register the cell in viewDidLoad()

```
 let SLQHomeTableViewCellID = "SLQHomeTableViewCellID"
 self.tableView.registerClass(SLQStatusCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: SLQHomeTableViewCellID)
```

then the dataSouce like below:

```
// MARK: - Table view data source
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
  return statuses?.count ?? 0
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(SLQHomeTableViewCellID, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SLQStatusCell
    let status = statuses![indexPath.row]
    cell.status = status
    return cell
}
```

i also override init()

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    // 初始化UI
    setupUI()

}
```

but when i run in simulator ,it's a  fatal error in register cell 
,this line is the error appeared

```
 self.tableView.registerClass(SLQStatusCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: SLQHomeTableViewCellID)

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

i want to why,i run the program in using OC is all right.

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: self.tableView.registerClass(SLQStatusCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: SLQHomeTableViewCellID)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: no, the error is appear on this line 
self.tableView.registerClass(SLQStatusCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: SLQHomeTableViewCellID)

Answer (score 0):

If the line with the `registerClass` method call is causing that error, then chances are good the tableView `IBOutlet` is not connected.  That is the most likely thing on that line of code that would be `nil`, as it probably has a type of `UITableView!` which is being implicitly unwrapped.

You can test this by setting a breakpoint and inspecting the value of `self.tableView` or with a simple `print("Table view: \(self.tableView)")` statement put above the existing `registerClass` line.

Comment: i am not using any xib or storyboard ,so using registerClass,and an print the class like below
<SLQSinaWeibo.SLQStatusCell: 0x7fa8cb8579e0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa8cb83b3f0>> + SLQHomeTableViewCellID
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

it cannot see any useful info